# Select query it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, group-by

I am getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ReportEmployeesOnLeave, Line 17
>   Column 'Employee.EmployeeId' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you miss a comma after `TotalAbsents`?

Comment: @GinoPane : don't worry it's commented code.

Comment: @Gino Pane bro that line is already commented.

Answer (score 1):

What about the error message don't you understand? It's pretty self-explanatory. What it means is: If you use a `group by`, all the selected attributes have to be either in the `group by` or in an aggregate function (`COUNT()`, `SUM()` etc.).

So, if you correct your `group by` you shouldn't have any errors:

```
...
GROUP BY   TC.Date
,          TC.DayName
,          TC.DayType
,          TC.ScheduleId
,          TC.LeaveTaken
,          TC.Remarks
,          E.EmployeeId
,          E.EmployeeNo
,          E.Name
,          E.ScheduleId
,          C.BusinessName
```

Whether this gives the result you're looking for, is another question.

For future questions: Please add code as text, not as a picture. That way answerers can simply copy-paste, rather than typing it all over.

**edit:** If you don't want to `group by` all of your selected attributes you can use window functions (assuming sql server 2012 or above):

```
SELECT       * -- Everything you need
,            COUNT(TC.AbsentCalculation) OVER(PARTITION BY E.Name, E.EmployeeId) AS AbsentCount
,            SUM(TC.AbsentCalculation) OVER(PARTITION BY E.Name, E.EmployeeId) AS TotalAbsents
FROM         ...
```

You won't need a `GROUP BY` at all if you implement this.

Comment: have tried allot to put in text format but i was getting this validation error “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted” from stackoverflow.

Comment: actually i wants to fetch the attendance records between 2 dates but i just wants to group by Name and EmployeeId, if i put every select in group by i can't get the desired all rows betweeen these 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

Write all the fields into `Group By` cause

Comment: actually i wants to fetch the attendance records between 2 dates but i just wants to group by Name and EmployeeId, if i put every select in group by i can't get the desired all rows betweeen these 2 dates.

Comment: Group by has a rule that which fields you write between select & from (i.e. fetch columns) without aggregate functions should be wrote in "Group By" Cause.